# Looking for advices for regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regex which has to match these patterns:
`\n 700000000123`

I mean this `"\n"+"white space"+"12 digits"`

So I tried:

`(\\\\)(n)(\\s)(\\d{12})`

or something like this:

`(\\\\)(n)(\\s)(\\[0-9]{12})`

But it still doesn't work. for me {12} means repeat a digit `\d` or `[0-9]`, 12 times ?

My idea is a java code which could check if a string contains this regex:

```
Boolean result = false;

String string_to_match = "a random string \n 700000000123"
String re1="(\\\\)";    
String re2="(n)";   
String re3="(\\s)"; 
String re4="([0-9]{11})";   

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);

if (string_to_match.contains(p.toString()){
      result = true;
}
```

I tried to use: http://www.txt2re.com/ to help me.

Have you any advices to build this regex ? I would like to understand why at the moment it doesn't work.

Comment: is '\n' The line break? If yes you have use it as one char. `(\\\n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\\\\n\\s+\\d{12}$
```

I guess this should work for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/33

Answer (score 1):

**You need to use `String#matches` instead of `String#contains` to match a regex.**

Following should work:

```
String re1="(\\n)";    
String re2="( )"; 
String re3="(\\d{12})";   

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
System.out.println("\n 700000000123".matches(p.pattern())); // true
```

Or simply:

```
System.out.println( "\n 700000000123".matches("(\n)( )(\\d{12})") ); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it up in a chain of invocations without compromising to matching the entire input.

For instance:

```
String input = "\n 700000000123";
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\n\\s\\d{12}").matcher(input).find());
```

**Output**

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

\n will work only in Unix machines.  In Windows it is \r\n.  Please use System.getProperty("line.separator") if you want your code to work both in linux and windows.

Use the following

System.out.println(Pattern.compile(System.getProperty("line.separator")+"\s\d{12}").matcher(input).find());